# Convert JavaUtilDate to NSDate and vice versa?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, swift, j2objc

I use [j2objc](https://github.com/google/j2objc) to translate a java util Date to a objective-c JavaUtilDate class.
I imported `#import "java/util/Date.h"`to store a translated java Date variable.

```
var myDate: JavaUtilDate
```

**How do I convert a `JavaUtilDate` into an `NSDate`?**

Comment: So what is a JavaUtilDate? Tell us that and somebody can help you.

Comment: @DuncanC Don't down vote this is a serious question. I use: JavaUtilDate  from https://github.com/google/j2objc

Comment: @confile Please edit your Question with additional info rather than posting comments.

Comment: If you don't want to get downvoted, and you want help, post enough information in your question so that iOS developers know enough about the problem to be able to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on where/how you get the Java Date, your best bet would be to get the milliseconds and instantiate the NSDate with it.

So call the getTime() method on the Java Date to get milliseconds since Epoch, then create your NSDate with the dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: method. The NSDate method takes seconds (as a floating point), so divide by 1000.0 to keep the precision (thanks to Martin R for pointing this out in comments).  :)

[Java Util Date method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime())

[NSDate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:)

---

There seems to be some confusion on what exactly is being asked. To be as general as possible, time objects typically have a method to get the milliseconds since epoch and a constructor (or setter) to pass in the seconds since epoch. So all you have to do is get the seconds from one object and instantiate the other object with the seconds.

Comment: NSDate takes seconds as a *floating point* value and has sub-second precision, so you should divide by 1000.0 instead of "chopping off"

Comment: My lack of objective-c knowledge is showing! Method said seconds, didn't dig into the actual types. Updated answer.  ;)

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question!!!

Comment: @confile: your questions is absolutely vague and leaves us guessing.

Comment: @confile: Is JavaUtilDate not the j2objc mapping of java.util.Date? Does it not have a getTime() method?

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is down voted. This is exactly what I would have said, based on the given information.

Comment: From what I have read of j2objc, it sounds like it translates all the methods of the object you convert. So there should be an equivalent of getTime. I appreciate the support Martin.  :)